# Trying to export stacked text to CAD using ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, export, autocad

I've been experiencing some unwanted results when trying to export stacked text to CAD using ArcGIS 10.2 for desktop. With the Export to CAD tool I can easily export polygons. However, I'm also trying to export the ***'stacked text'*** labels inside those polygons.

With the Feature to Point tool I then export a *'CADtype'* field that was created with the *'Add Field'* routine and populated with values from other fields using the 'Field Calculator' tool. 
My results are the correct text values exported to the centroid of each polygon but no longer stacked in columns, and a **"?"** at the end of each line. There are no error or warning messages generated.

I've tried both VBScript and Python expressions for the Field Calculator syntax but I'm getting the same results. I can't use the ArcGIS for AutoCAD plugin because the CAD on my machine is not current enough and I don't have FME.

Comment: See if export labels to annotation and export annotation to cad will work.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be that AutoCAD couldn't handle stacked text. We always just had separate lines of text in CAD if they were multiple lines. I imagine it can handle it better now, but I still can't help but think there are some conversion issues there. I would do single line labels in ArcGIS and see if that exports to AutoCAD better.